# CSS3 Image Slider: On hover, pause button not appearing in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

This is the first website I've ever built so be easy on me!!!

I built this CSS3 image slider from a tutorial online and it works great. It slides from right to left, keeping the images outside of the slider hidden until they slide in. On hover, the slider pauses it's animation and a pause button appears over the images, and disappears once hovered off of it. Everything works great in all browsers except IE, the pause button wont show.

Any ideas?!?! I'm tearing my hair out over this!

Here's the CSS for the pause button animation,

```
div#css3slider:hover {
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
-o-animation-play-state: paused;
animation-play-state: paused;
}}

div#css3slider img {
float: right;
}

div#slidercontainer:after {
content: "❚❚";
font-size: 165px;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
-webkit-transition: 1s;
-ms-transition: 1s;
-moz-transition: 1s;
-o-transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;
left: 550px;
top: 130px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.8px  rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
}

div#slidercontainer:hover:after {
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
-moz-animation-play-state: paused;
-o-animation-play-state: paused;
animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `content: "❚❚";` with something else, maybe `content: "test";`, to make sure it's not a character escaping problem. Also try adding `-ms-*` wherever you have browser prefixes just to be safe. For example, add `-ms-animation-play-state` etc.

Comment: Good ideas, but no cigar! Thanks for the response though.

Comment: What version of IE? You should check to see if the pseudoselectors (`:after`) and rgba color is supported. Try change the rgba color to a normal hex code (`color: #bada55`).

Comment: Just noticed it works in IE 11 and not 10. Thanks man, I think you hit the nail on the head.